# Skipping observable emissions after first pending one

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5, redux-observable

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');

var obs1 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click').scan(count => count + 1, 0).multicast(new Rx.Subject())

function obs2$(result) {
  return Rx.Observable.of(result).delay((Math.random() * 10000 % 2000) + 1000)
}

obs1.concatMap((count) => {
  return obs2$(count)
}).subscribe(x => console.log("Sync Finished " + x))

obs1.subscribe(x => console.log("Sync Request  " + x))

obs1.connect()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.3.0/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>

<button>Click me</button>

<h3 id='show'>Foo</h3>
```

I am implementing a syncing system with two observables in play. One is just a stream of sync request actions:

```
actions$.ofType('SYNC_REQUESTED')
```

`actions$` in this case is a [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org) construct representing Redux actions.

The other observable performs the actual sync and dispatches a Redux action when it is completed.

I want it to behave such that if a sync is currently being performed, and another emission is made to the sync request observable, the sync gets queued up (like in the case of `concatMap`). However, if multiple emissions are made during a sync, only one of them is actually taken.

In other words, I want a `switchMap` that doesn't cancel the current sync.

If you run the attached snippet and click the button five times in a row within a second you'll see:

```
Sync Request  1
Sync Request  2
Sync Request  3
Sync Request  4
Sync Request  5
Sync Finished 5
```

If you use `switchMap`.

And using `concatMap` you'll see:

```
Sync Request  1
Sync Request  2
Sync Request  3
Sync Request  4
Sync Request  5
Sync Finished 1
Sync Finished 2
Sync Finished 3
Sync Finished 4
Sync Finished 5
```

I want it read:

```
Sync Request  1
Sync Request  2
Sync Request  3
Sync Request  4
Sync Request  5
Sync Finished 1
Sync Finished 5
```

Now because I am using Redux I could always use the store to help me out, maybe keeping track of `syncPending` and `syncInProgress` flags and using `skipWhile` to skip sync requests that happen while a sync is in progress if there's already one pending.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this just by using RxJS though since that would require extra code / actions / reducers / Redux state.

Answer (score 0):

try take(1) and repeat()

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');

var obs1 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click').scan(count => count + 1, 0).multicast(new Rx.Subject())

function obs2$(result) {
  return Rx.Observable.of(result).delay(2000)
}


Rx.Observable.merge(obs1.audit(()=>obs1.mergeMap(obs2$)),
obs1.take(1).mergeMap(obs2$).repeat())
.subscribe(console.log)

obs1.subscribe(x => console.log("Sync Request  " + x))
obs1.connect()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.3.0/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>

<button>Click me</button>

<h3 id='show'>Foo</h3>
```

Comment: This does the the first sync but when it finishes it doesn't do a second one. So you'll have requests 1,2,3, and 4, but then only have a sync finished for 1, not for 4.

Comment: It will fire if 4 is trigger after the sync period, you can keep clicking and see the effect. Bascially it just ignores all the click sysnc when sync is in progress.

Comment: You're right but I want it to ignore all of the clicks while sync is in progress EXCEPT one of them. So if any clicks happen while a sync is in progress I want only one additional sync to happen afterwards.

Comment: that's a more complex use case, use a state variable may be the easy way out. or you can look into audit operator and combine some other technique

Comment: Modified the code and fit your requirement. Bascially first stream take the last emission and second one take the first.

Comment: This gives you:

Sync Request  1
Sync Request  2
Sync Request  3
Sync Request  4
Sync Request  5
Sync Request  6
Sync Request  7
Sync Request  8
1
Sync Request  9
9
Sync Request  10
Sync Request  11
9
11 ---- (Sync 9 happened twice there).  


Because it uses mergeMap it does things in parallel which is not desired (if syncing was idempotent I would just use switchMap).

Comment: ya it does run in parallel, looks like simple way is to use state variable. Or use subject to track emission

Comment: Yeah I agree. Think using the store state might be the best bet, or making syncing idempotent and using switchMap and just giving up on the idea all-together. Appreciate the help!